# delete automatically from list

Tags: android

i use list with `Custom Adapter`
 which is extends 
`ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>`
so i can delete specific item from database if i press button delete 
it delete from database but it is appear in the list unless the user go to other activity and return back to that interface
is there is a way that i can delete automatically after the user select the item from the list

code

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> student;
    student.remove(id);
```

i try to do this but it is not work

Answer (score 0):

After removal, call:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to notify the adapter about the change.

Comment: after i do  setListAdapter(adapter);
   ((ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged(); but dose not work ?

Comment: i have class m that i set the adapter and class custom adapter that i do my function delete

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter;
...
yourListView.setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```